# passing a parameter in the reverse url in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

javascript

```
   var url = '{% url cand_resume "cnd_id" %}';   
   url = url.replace("cnd_id",id);
   cell2.innerHTML= '<a href="' + url + '"> View</a>';
```

id is the variable (1000)

urls.py

```
       url(r'^(?P<cnd_id>\d*)/resume/', 'download_resume',name='cand_resume'),
```

it throws this error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'cand_resume' with arguments '(u'cnds_id',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you parse your url

```
var url = '{% url cand_resume "cnd_id" %}';
```

you sending a string **cnd_id** which will **not** match your url.

try (not sure if you need quite around your function name)

```
var url = '{% url cand_resume 1000 %}';
```

or something like (id is variable from django)

```
var url = '{% url cand_resume id %}';
```

---

You can try dirty trick like

```
var url = '{% url cand_resume 1000 %}'.replace (1000, cnd_id);
```

or check out this lib https://github.com/mlouro/django-js-utils

Comment: maybe 1000 is not the best placeholder (unless the id is limited to 999)!