# Reverse all arguments JS

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, reverse

I'm trying a JavaScript challenge and I can't figure out how to approach it. Trying to replicate the _.flip Lodash method. I've been able to negate all arguments a function passes doing this:

```
function invert(func) {
  return function () {
    return !func(...arguments);
  }
};
```

But can't figure out how to reverse them instead of negate them. I've seen [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634078/passing-a-parameter-in-the-reverse-url-in-javascript) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495310/why-is-this-javascript-function-not-reversing-the-array) talking about reverse methods, but don't contemplate the idea of several arguments.

Anyone knows how to approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function flip(func) {
    return function() {
        func(...Array.from(arguments).reverse());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used/seen .from before. Would you mind telling me what it does there? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, `Array.from()` accepts any iterable object as its argument, and creates an array from it. `var arr = Array.from(obj)` is equivalent to `var arr = []; for (var item of obj) arr.push(item);` You can read up on it, and other array methods, on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: A question - won't there will be a `return` before invoking `func`?

Answer (score 2):

With arrow functions, this is possible:

```
const flip = f => (...args) => f(...args.reverse())
```